# Stm32f429 usb cdc to pc

Tags: serial, uart, usb-device

I want to put together a simple library to communicate between stm32f429 and pc via usb cdc vcp. I noticed many examples from stm create a usb uart bridge on the mcu. I am trying to understand the usefulness in this. Why is the uart needed? Can you not communicate directly via usb cdc to pc? Perhaps the main feature would be setting a specific speed? Not sure, could somebody help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your device enumerates itself as CDC-ACM, you get the benefit of being able to access it as if it was a generic serial port.

The ACM subclass was intended for USB-to-UART converters and therefore the data stream generated at the PC side contains not only the actual characters sent to the VCP, but also the control messages to set baudrate, do handshaking etc.

When there is no physical serial port on the device, you can ignore the control messages (acknowledge and/or return bogus values) because the port setting has no influence on data flowing between PC and the MCU.

Comment: Thanks. That must explain u with double dots above I kept seeing when I started the connection. Is there a way to handle these control messages without the uart?

Comment: At least Set_control_line_state, Set_line_coding and get_line_coding are mandatory. All is described in the official CDC specifications.